# Loop to shift elements in array to the end

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, higher-order-functions

Assuming I have an array

```
let arr = [
    [0,1,0,4],
    [1,0,1,2],
    [0,0,1,1],
    [0,1,0,1]
];
```

I want to loop through the array with a higher order array function, and return an array where all values that are not equal to `n` (in my case let's say `n=0`) will be stacked against the end of the array:

```
console.log( arr.map( certainFunction ) );
//returns this;
[ [0,0,1,4],
  [0,1,1,2],
  [0,0,1,1],
  [0,0,1,1] ]
```

Is it possible using higher order functions to loop through `arr` and return the array above?
Then how will the `certainFunction` look?

Comment: Does the order matter? Also, does it matter for numbers that are less than n?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A higher-order func, as ordered ;)

```js
let separate = n => a => a.filter(x => x === n).concat(a.filter(x => x !== n));

//

let arr = [
    [0,1,0,4],
    [1,0,1,2],
    [0,0,1,1],
    [0,1,0,1]
];


newArr = arr.map(separate(1)) // move 1's to the start

console.log(newArr.map(x => x.join()))
```

or, with some more functional programming:

```
let eq = a => b => a === b;
let not = f => a => !f(a);

let separate = n => a => a.filter(eq(n)).concat(a.filter(not(eq(n))));
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done linearly by keeping a goalpost and pushing all `arr[i] != n` back to this index.

```
function push_to_end (arr, n=0) {
  // Begin by pushing items to the very end.
  let index = arr.length - 1
  for (let i = index; i > -1; i--) {
    // If you encounter an integer not equal to end, place it
    // at `index` and move the goalpost back one spot.
    if (arr[i] !== n)
      arr[index--] = arr[i]
  }

  // Fill everything up to the goalpost with `n`, as that is how
  // many times we observed n.
  for (let i = 0; i <= index; i++) {
    arr[i] = n
  }

  return arr
}
```

In your case, you would apply this function to each array in your array of arrays:

```
arr.map(a => push_to_end(a, n))
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```js
let arr = [
    [0,1,0,4],
    [1,0,1,2],
    [0,0,1,1],
    [0,1,0,1]
];

arr = arr.map(ar => ar.sort((a, b) => a-b));
console.log(arr)
```

Works in your case, not sure if you wanted numbers less than `n` to work too

Comment: This is much slower than it needs to be.

Comment: slower? How big are these arrays? Have you considered something like a database, or are you counting milliseconds?

Comment: You don't need to sort the arrays. Plus, sorting is not necessarily the correct answer, e.g. if there are negative integers or if `n=2`.